# How to solve "Service Unavailable" when deploying Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy an azure function using the following command:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "resourcegroup" -n "function-app" --src MyFunction.zip --debug
```

But I get a **BadRequest** error.

The debug flag allows me to see the detailed request that cause the issue:

```
urllib3.connectionpool: https://management.azure.com:443 "POST /subscriptions/**uuid**/resourceGroups/**resourcegroup**/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/**function-app**/syncfunctiontriggers?api-version=2019-08-01 HTTP/1.1" 400 346
msrest.http_logger: Response status: 400
msrest.http_logger: Response headers:
msrest.http_logger:     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
msrest.http_logger:     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
msrest.http_logger:     'Content-Length': '346'
msrest.http_logger:     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
msrest.http_logger:     'Expires': '-1'
msrest.http_logger:     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
msrest.http_logger:     'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
msrest.http_logger:     'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319'
msrest.http_logger:     'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET'
msrest.http_logger:     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes': '1199'
msrest.http_logger:     'x-ms-request-id': '**removed**'
msrest.http_logger:     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': '**removed**'
msrest.http_logger:     'x-ms-routing-request-id': '**removed**'
msrest.http_logger:     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
msrest.http_logger:     'Date': 'Tue, 08 Jun 2021 16:20:41 GMT'
msrest.http_logger: Response content:
msrest.http_logger: {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."}}],"Innererror":null}
msrest.exceptions: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 659, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 722, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 715, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 693, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 330, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 786, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 383, in enable_zip_deploy_functionapp
    return upload_zip_to_storage(cmd, resource_group_name, name, src, slot)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 584, in upload_zip_to_storage
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 577, in upload_zip_to_storage
    client.web_apps.sync_function_triggers(resource_group_name, name)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/mgmt/web/v2019_08_01/operations/_web_apps_operations.py", line 26131, in sync_function_triggers
    raise models.DefaultErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.models._models_py3.DefaultErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: BadRequestError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'
```

How can I fix this  **`BadRequest (Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime)`** error and what does it mean?

Comment: Could you please try to remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` from app settings?

Comment: Did not have to try it as it is working fine now. 

I think it was linked to Fastly outage but Azure's status website was displaying a "OK" status the entire day when all the community managed status websites seems to have registered an increase in complaint yesterday.